# How to convert String to an Array In Java?

Tags: java, json

I have a String and I want convert it to a String array without using a JsonObject.
I searched many topics, but I can't solve my problem.

My String is like:

```
String str="[{"India":{"State":"Gujarat","City":"Rajkot","Pin":360330,"Place":"AT Rajkot"}}]";
```

And I want output As Array like:

```
India  
    Gujarat  
    Rajkot  
    360330  
    AT Rajkot
```

How can I get an array like that output, without using jsonObject?

Comment: You need to use `JsonObject`.

Comment: That's like asking, `How can I screw in a screw without a screwdriver`?

Comment: You *need* to use `JSONObject`. If you don't want to use it, you'll have to make a class which can hold the informations as you want and then write a parser for the JSON string. In that case, good luck

Comment: Do you have a recipe for onion soup I can have? One thing, I'd like it with no onion please.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking how to parse JSON.  You need to use a `JsonObject` or another JSON library. If you want to learn how to do this, read the several thousand lines of source code in `JsonObject` and learn how to write a JSON parser. Then, write a JSON parser, which will do what you want.

In other words, what you are asking is not technically incorrect, but ridiculous.

Comment: Means i can't convert string to array without jsonobject?

Comment: @user3209751 - As he said, `learn how to write a JSON parser. Then, write a JSON parser, which will do what you want.`

Comment: Okay Friends I try to solve my problems that ways...